# Onde chamar SaveChanges() quanto tiver vários repositórios?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com Entity Framework, com vários repositórios.

Cada repositório encapsula `SaveChanges()` do DbContext.

Quando uma operação da camada de negócios usa vários repositórios, e houver alteração nos dados, preciso chamar `SaveChanges()` somente uma vez.

Obviamente, posso fazê-lo em qualquer repositório, mas me parece estranho ter que chamar um aleatoriamente. Qual é a recomendação nesta situação?

### EDITADO

Os repositórios só estão em interfaces por enquanto, não há implementação, segue uma delas

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
   User getByID(string ID);
   User getByIDWithActiveGlossaries(string ID);
   IEnumerable<User> getAll();

   bool Save();
}
```

E há outros repositórios, todos implementando `Save()`. Save está em uma interface base, coloquei junto aqui para simplificar. Save vai chamar `SaveChanges()` do `DbContext`.

<strike>PS: Avaliei o uso de `UnitOfWork`, mas descartei, não vendo necessidade. É por isso, alias, que chamo `SaveChanges()` no final de uma operação completa, que pode envolver várias alterações.</strike>

### EDIÇÃO FINAL

Eu tinha descartado o uso de Unit of Work pois não havia necessidade de um mecanismo para agrupar as operações, uma vez que `SaveChanges()` já é "tudo ou nada" (todas as operações com sucesso ou todas são revertidas).

Contudo, graças às respostas de Hokos e Dherik, percebi que `Unit of Work` não tem só essa funcionalidade, mas também permite agrupar a operação de `Save()`.

Comment: Poderia por um exemplo da forma que seu repositório está feito?

Comment: Isso vai depender muito da implementação que você está utilizando, por exemplo, se estiver usando injeção de dependencia o tratamento pode ser feito por meio do objeto de contexto que é compartilhado entre os repositórios

Comment: @JulioBorges Então, foi exatamente o que eu ia fazer quando pensei: Ei, não quero expor o DbContext na camada de negócios... aí vi que deveria haver um método `Save()` nas interfaces, mas surgiu a dúvida de onde salvar quando houvesse vários repositórios na mesma operação.

Comment: Removi minha resposta, não tinha visto sua observação sobre ter descartado o Unit of Work. Mas não ficou claro, para mim, o motivo de você ter descartado. De qualquer modo, você vai precisar criar o context em um lugar único e passar para todos os repositórios para atingir seu objetivo, e o Unit Of Work ajuda a organizar isto.

Comment: @Dherik Eu descartei Unit Of Work porque não precisava de um mecanismo para garantir integridade nas operações, o que para mim é a razão principal para unit of work: garantir que todas as operações têm sucesso, ou que nenhuma é executada. Mas vendo sua resposta pensei que Unit Of Work também serve para centralizar o controle do DbContext, que é o que eu preciso. Volte sua resposta, vou aceitar e editar minha pergunta para ficar completa.

Comment: @RSinohara, entendi. A princípio achei que você precisava da integridade das operações entre os repositórios. Voltei minha resposta pois, mesmo que não seja a solução preterida para o seu caso, pode ajudar outras pessoas com um problema parecido que chegarem até a sua dúvida.

Comment: @Dherik Na verdade repensei a situação, como mencionei na pergunta (não sei se era o jeito mais adequado de colocar isso, mas eu não queria simplesmente remover a menção ao Unit of Work).

Comment: Opa, demorei pra ver e a galera já bombou a resposta, realmente o melhor é o Unit Of Work, combinando isso com Dependency Injection com certeza atende à sua necessidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que o [pattern Unit Of Work](http://www.devmedia.com.br/unit-of-work-o-padrao-de-unidade-de-trabalho-net/25811) vai resolver seu problema.

Com ele, resumidamente, você cria uma unidade de trabalho e adiciona os repositórios nele. Ao final, você chama o `Commit()` da unidade de trabalho.

Mesmo que não deseje compartilhar o mesmo `context` entre os repositórios, você pode usar a ideia do Unit of Work como base para a solução.

[Aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576681/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusRepository) você pode encontrar um exemplo mais completo, com múltiplos repositórios.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar seu método `Save()` para receber uma transação. Dessa forma você poderia verificar, se uma transação foi informada, só adiciona o objeto no contexto e da o commit na transação depois de chamar todos os `Save()`. Uma outra abordagem seria quando não passar a transação, ai você poderia dar o SaveChanges direto dentro do método, fica implícito que apenas um objeto está sendo salvo.

```
public bool Save(TransactionScope transaction = null)
{
    if(transaction != null)
    {
     //Aqui você apenas adiciona o objeto no contexto.
    }
    else
    {
     //Aqui você salva direto o objeto.
    }
}
```

Depois de passar pelos N `Save()` que você vai fazer, basta dar um Commit na transação. Caso não tenha N, chamou um `Save()` salvou e pronto.

Comment: O cenário que descrevi não é o melhor a ser feito (na minha opinião). Eu não faria o Save() separado em cada repositório, faria no máximo um método que "prepara" a entidade para ser salva e depois salvo ela com meu contexto.